# How to format Index() without TZ information in R?

Tags: r, xts

I would like to test if the date of the last row of an xts object is equal to the current date. My problem is that `last(index(obj))` returns the timezone information the `Sys.Date()` function doesn't.

```
> last(index(obj))
[1] "2016-09-16 UTC"

> Sys.Date()
[1] "2016-09-16"
```

The workaround I have is to `paste0` `Sys.Date()` and `Sys.timezone()` but it not elegant. Is there a better solution ?

```
# Test if we already have data
  if (last(index(obj)) == paste0(Sys.Date(), " ", Sys.timezone())) {

    next

  }
```

*** EDIT ***

More info :

```
> str(obj)
An ‘xts’ object on 2013-06-01/2016-09-16 containing:
  Data: num [1:1204, 1:6] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "Open" "High" "Low" "Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 1
 $ dateFormat: chr "Date"
```

Thank you,

Comment: I see that the `dateFormat` attribute is `"Date"` but the index class is `POSIXct`. How did you create `obj`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timezone is printed because `index(obj)` is a `POSIXct` class object. If you want to compare the output of `index(obj)` with the output from `Sys.Date()`, you need to ensure that the output of `index` is a `Date` class object. There are a couple ways to accomplish this:

1) Directly convert the output of `index` to `Date`:

```
as.Date(last(index(obj))) == Sys.Date()
```

2) Convert the entire index of `obj` to `Date` (note that the index class is currently `POSIXct`):

```
indexClass(obj) <- "Date"
last(index(obj)) == Sys.Date()
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrich, the second solution you provide is perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem comes from the POSIXct time format of my object. Converting to `Date` with `as.Date(last(index(obj)))` solve my problem.